# Change href attribute of link on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I simply try to change the value of the href

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  $("a#link1").attr("href").val("www.bing.de");
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link1" href="www.google.de">LINK</a>
<div>Click here</div>
```

But this throws the error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr(...).val is not a function` and I don't know why? As far as I know `val` IS a function.

Comment: In cases like this it's always best to read the docs: http://api.jquery.com/attr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

You can't change an attribute with `val()` method. `val()` is use only for input value.

You can use `attr("aatribute_name",value);` or `prop("attribute_name","value");`

```js
$("div").click(function() {
  $("a#link1").attr("href","www.bing.de");
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link1" href="www.google.de">LINK</a>
<div>Click here</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `attr` or [**prop**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

```
$("a#link1").prop("href","www.bing.de")
```

It is the attribute value that you want to change not `val`. [**val**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) is basically use to get the value and some time set the value, but not the attribute.

Comment: @EdwardBlack Because you are trying to use jq `val()` method on a string

Answer (score 1):

Try the following snippet.

Problem is here: `$("a#link1").attr("href").val("www.bing.de");`

```js
$("div").click(function(){
 $("a#link1").attr("href","www.bing.de");
});
```

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="link1" href="www.google.de">LINK</a>
<div>Click here</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript implementation using **[`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)** :

```
document.querySelector("a#link1").setAttribute("href", "www.bing.de");
//or
document.querySelector("a#link1").href = "www.bing.de";
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assign with href is also working

```
$("div").click(function() {
   $("a#link1")[0].href = "www.bing.de";
});
```

Comment: I tried with javascript standard ,so need to index ! Example if there is two `a href ` link , index will be 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

.val() is used for inputs, selects and textareas. It should be called like this:

```
$("div").click(function() {
  $("a#link1").attr('href','www.bing.de');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why it was not working because you were trying assign value to `anchor tag`. `val()` doesn't assigns value to `anchor tag`. For that you have to use method as below.

Not this :-

```
$("div").click(function() {
  $("a#link1").attr("href").val("www.bing.de");
});
```

This one -

```
  $("div").click(function() {
      $("a#link1").attr("href","www.bing.de");
    });
```